# How to display a hidden element in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Is it possible to have an element hidden by default (so that it does not show if JavaScript is off) and have AngularJS override the style to display it?

I have a function on the scope that should be returning an overriding style to display the element:

```
$scope.style = function() {
  return { "display": "block!important" };
}
```

The element itself has the original CSS hiding it as well as an `ng-style` directive:

```
<h4 class="original" ng-style="style()">
```

The CSS hides the element at first:

```
.original {
  display: none;
}
```

There is a non-working [demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cpsrZijG26DbGUyikswF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works.
The actual problem is here:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

White (`#fff`) text on a white background. Remove `color: #fff;` and it will work.

Here's a [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/gFZhfFr7ny7vQasD5m8X?p=preview) plunker.

Also, `!important` [does not work](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5379) with `ng-style`.

Comment: The !important was the breaking point. Did not know about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-class`:

```
<p class="hidden" ng-class="{visible: show}">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

Then have two CSS classes:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;  
}
.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

And add the `show` property to the scope (it can be an ng-model as well):

```
$scope.show = true;
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/qibu/1/edit

Comment: I was writing exactly this, this is the proper way to show/hide a div.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It is hidden by default. If there's no JavaScript then Angular won't run and the ng-class attribute won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ng-class

```
.show {
    display: block !important;
}

<h4 class="original" ng-class="{show: isJSon}">

$scope.isJSon = true;
```